# In ggplot and sportyR packages: how to fill white space outside the pitch with others colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Bellow is my code:

```
library(sportyR)
library(ggplot2)
geom_basketball('nba', full_surf = FALSE, rotate = TRUE)
```

This is the github page: https://github.com/sportsdataverse/sportyR

I have to change the color of the white space outside the court chart. For example, I did this:

```
theme(panel.spacing = unit(0,'cm'),
              legend.position = 'top',
              plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'red', color = 'whitesmoke'),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'red', color = 'whitesmoke'))
```

And it didnt work. I already tried everything.

Any help?

PS: (EDITED)
This is the output that I have when I do:

```
geom_basketball('nba', full_surf = FALSE, rotate = TRUE,
                substitution_area_color = 'red',
                court_apron_color = 'red')
```

[image]

I still have white spaces. Note the ("Plot made with sportyR" text area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author/maintainer of `sportyR`. Apologies for not seeing this when you originally posted your question!

Not sure if you ever resolved the issue, but what I think you're trying to do isn't entirely possible with `v1.0.1`, the version that was on CRAN at the time you posted the question. You were on the right path with what you posted in the `theme()` above, but you need to *add* the theme to the call to `geom_basketball()` like this (using orange as my background color):

```r
geom_basketball("nba") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ff552e")
  )
```

this wasn't possible in the initial version of the package. The good news is that in `v2.0.0` this is possible by using the `color_updates` parameter in `geom_basketball()` like so:

```r
library(sportyR)
library(ggplot2)

geom_basketball(
  "nba",
  color_updates = list(
      plot_background = "#ff552e"
  )
)
```

[image: Plot of basketball court with orange background from sportyR v1.0.1]

However, the area where `Plot made via sportyR` is written is actually a plot caption, not a part of the plot/panel, so all you'd be able to control would be the caption's text color. This was removed in a later release (not released on CRAN).

The good news is that `v2.0.0` should be on CRAN within the next 24 hours or so (if it's not already by the time you're reading this answer). There were a few breaking changes from the last CRAN version that were necessary to make the package much more flexible (see changes [here](https://sportyr.sportsdataverse.org/news/index.html) for more explanation), but the argument you'll need is the `color_updates` argument, within which you'll want to set the `plot_background` color:

```r
library(sportyR)

geom_basketball(
  "nba",
  color_updates = list(
    plot_background = "#ff552e",
    # Changing the court apron, which is the outer-most feature
    # that v2.0.0 plots for basketball courts, to light blue
    court_apron = "#0088ce"
  )
)
```

which will produce this plot:

[image: Plot of basketball court with orange background from sportyR v2.0.0]

If this wasn't what you were looking to do, please let me know so I can help further. And, if I could make a slight request for future issues, please add them as issues on the [GitHub](https://github.com/sportsdataverse/sportyR) so I can be directly notified (and hopefully more immediately helpful!). Even just a link to and/or a copy/paste from the StackOverflow question would be great. I try to help with issues as quick as I can, but unfortunately the only way I directly am notified is through GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the github, there seems to be some areas you can color like court apron. Do you want something like this:

```
library(sportyR)
library(ggplot2)
geom_basketball('nba', full_surf = FALSE, rotate = TRUE,
                substitution_area_color = 'white',
                court_apron_color = 'white')
```

Output:

[image]

### Rmarkdown

Code:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: '2022-05-14'
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(sportyR)
library(ggplot2)
geom_basketball('nba', full_surf = FALSE, rotate = TRUE,
                substitution_area_color = 'white',
                court_apron_color = 'white'
                )
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want all area around the court to in whitesmoke color when I render it. It stills some white space left.

Comment: @Laura, You mean around the court by where the players don't play the game? I am not sure what you mean by "around the court".

Comment: @Laura, check output Rmarkdown.

Comment: I edited the question. Note that the text "Plot made via sportyR" still have a white background.

Comment: If you change the color to red you will be able to see that we still have white spaces. My question is: How to "extend" the background color to the text "Plot made via sportyR" area